# Ensuring field is only updated by one thread after Semaphore is released C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, dotnet-httpclient

I have a `DelegatingHandler` which is passed in the constructor of a singleton `HttpClient`.

This handler is responsible for doing a basic authentication to obtain a bearer token, which is used for subsequent requests until the token expires. Once the token expires, the basic authentication is triggered again, to refresh the token and so on.

```
public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string baseAddress;
    private readonly string user;
    private readonly string pass;

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim sem;
    private Token token;

    public MyMessageHandler() : base()
    {
        // validation/assignment of baseAddress, userName, password
        // ..omitted for brevity

        sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        // this is the first time, so get the token
        token = GetTokenAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.AccessToken}");
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // if a token refresh is needed
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && whateverOtherCheckToTriggerTokenRefresh
        {
            try
            {
                // don't want multiple requests refreshing the token
                await sem.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                token = await GetTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // we have the token, now set the headers to the new values
                request.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.AccessToken}");

                // replay the request with the new token
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                sem.Release();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{user}:{pass}");
        var basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);

        var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        };

        // get ourselves a token using basic auth
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(new Uri(baseAddress), "/token"))
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)
        };

        message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicAuthToken);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(message, new CancellationToken()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

       // return our token
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(result);
    }
}
```

I have used a `Semaphore` during the refresh/update token step, as this is a concurrent WCF app and I don't want multiple requests all requesting a new token. Once the refresh step is done, the `token` field of `MyMessageHandler` is set to the new `Token` object returned by `GetTokenAsync()` and the semaphore is released, so other waiting requests will enter the code block.

1) How do I now prevent the requests that were stuck waiting on the `await sem.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` line from performing the refresh token step themselves?

2) Should I be concerned about incoming requests attempting to grab the value of  `token` field while it's being updated in the semaphore? If so, should I do something like `Interlocked.Exchange(ref token, newlyFetchedToken);` as soon as the new token is fetched?

**Update**:

After Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer, here is my approach to implement his answer. I'm still having difficulties to understand how to implement the answer.

```
public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string baseAddress;
    private readonly string user;
    private readonly string pass;

    private TaskToken> tokenTask;

    public MyMessageHandler() : base()
    {
        // validation/assignment of baseAddress, userName, password
        // ..omitted for brevity
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var localTokenTask = tokenTask;
        Token localToken;

        if (!request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {localToken.AccessToken}");
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // if a token refresh is needed
        if (whateverOtherCheckToTriggerTokenRefresh)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Token>();

            if (localTokenTask != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref tokenTask, tcs.Task, localTokenTask))
            {
                // get latest value of Task<Token> field locally
                localTokenTask = tokenTask;
                localToken = await localTokenTask;
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue($"{localToken.TokenType}", $"{localToken.AccessToken}");
            }
            else
            {
                var newToken = await GetTokenAsync();
                tcs.SetResult(newToken);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue($"{newToken.TokenType}", $"{newToken.AccessToken}");
            }
        }
        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{user}:{pass}");
        var basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);

        var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        };

        // get ourselves a token using basic auth
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(new Uri(baseAddress), "/token"))
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)
        };

        message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicAuthToken);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(message, new CancellationToken()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

       // return our token
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all those `ConfigureAwait(false)`? They are only needed on desktop applications and then only if you don't want to return to the original synchronization context

Comment: As for using a semaphore in a handler, that's a very bad idea. HttpClient is thread-safe. The handlers should be thread safe without locking too. Calls to different URLs will still call the *same* handler, especially if a single HttpClient instance is used. This means there may be multiple tokens. These can be stored in a concurrent collection, eg a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They are not "only needed in desktop applications".  It's appropriate anytime the function doesn't rely on anything from the requesting synchronization context.  Of course, in this case the code *does* rely on it, as it's looking through request data after many of the awaits, but all those not followed by any usage of the current context would benefit from not doing unneeded synchronization.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. The `HttpClient` will only be used for one particular API, and only one token (at a time) is needed to authenticate against all the endpoints of the API.

Comment: @Servy I know and at one point I'll create a standard, comment-sized disclaimer snippet explaining all this, plus that only certain types of applications have a synchronization context. This was a comment though.  Right now this code needs cleaning up before it can be fixed - eg that `GetTokenAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @globetrotter HttpClient is meant to work asynchronously. You could use a Lazy<T> to initialize the token along with `InterlockedCompareExchange` to replace it when it expires, to ensure that only one call can create a new Lazy<T> to initialize the token, all others would get and await that `Lazy<T>`

Comment: @globetrotter I'd also look into how similar handlers are implemented. This isn't a unique requirement after all, many third-party authentication providers work this way.

Comment: hi @PanagiotisKanavos do you have an example? I can find examples similar to [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/source/IdentityModel.Shared/Client/RefreshTokenHandler.cs) which seem to use semaphores. I'm trying to find an example similar to what Damien_The_Unbeliever posted but I'm still trying to wrap my head on how to implement his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside some other issues (empty `catch` blocks and the assumption that a single `HttpRequestMessage` instance can actually be sent more than once), what I'd normally have as the field would be a `Task<Token>`.

In outgoing requests, grab a copy of this field into a local variable and then `await` the actual token. If you get back an unauthorized response, create a new `TaskCompletionSource` and do an `InterlockedCompareExchange` to swap the `Task` in the field. If the exchange was successful, it's now "your" responsibility to renew the token and complete the `Task`.

However, if the `InterlockedCompareExchange` failed, it means that someone else has, or is in the process of, replacing the token. Loop back up to the top of your method and `await` this new `Task<Token>` instead.

No semaphores, quite simple behaviour to reason about. It's possible that even the new `Token` will also have expired by the time you try to use it - so be prepared to loop multiple times and have some strategy in place so that you don't loop forever if something else is at play and there's no real problem with the tokens.

And remove the empty `catch`.

Comment: A `Lazy<T>` instead of a TCS may make the code easier to read. Or not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - ah, but you can't `await` the built-in `Lazy<T>`. You have to poll or block.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I've tried implementing your answer but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. I've updated my question to include an attempt to implement your answer but it feels like I'm heading in the wrong direction. Do you mind having a look?

Comment: @globetrotter - you should be doing the `InterlockedCompareExchange` *before* you attempt to get a new token. If it fails, it means that *some other thread replaced it before you* - so instead take *its* `Task<Token>` and await it. Let your `TaskCompletionSource` get GCed - you lost the race to be the one to attempt to replace the token.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos & Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is confusing me. How will `InterlockedCompareExchange` correctly identify that the `Task<Token>` field has changed (when compared to the local copy of the fieldw in `SendAsync`)? The `Task<Token>` is a reference type, wouldn't both the global field and local copy always be the same? (see the code in my original question if my question is confusing)